# How to pick elements in even index and odd index?

Tags: haskell, recursion

I have a list, I want to break the list into two, one with elements in the even indexes, and the other from the odd indexes.

`breakByIndexes :: [a] -> ([a], [a])`

For example:

```
> breakByIndexes ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
(["A", "C"], ["B", "D"]

> breakByIndexes ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
(["A", "C", "E"], ["B", "D"]
```

I got a solution like this

```
breakByIndexes [] = ([], [])
breakByIndexes [e] = ([e], [])
breakByIndexes (e:o:xs) =
  let (es, os) = breakByIndexes xs
   in (e : es, o : os)
```

But I'm curious is it possible to implement without using recursion? 
And is it possible to implement by composing existing functions from `Data.List`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you are right, using the `partition` function from `Data.List`.

```
Prelude Data.List> (s, u) = partition (even . fst) (zip [0 .. ] "ABCD")
Prelude Data.List> (_, s2) = unzip s
Prelude Data.List> (_, u2) = unzip u
Prelude Data.List> (s2, u2)
("AC","BD")
```

How I found this? Go to [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) and fill in `[a] -> ([a], [a])`.

Answer (score 6):

My favourite version of this function uses `foldr`

```
pairs = foldr (\x ~(ys,zs) -> (x:zs,ys)) ([],[])
```

It works by swapping the tuple around on each item in the list. Inside the closure:

```
\x ~(odds,evens) -> (x:evens, odds)
```

You add on the `x`, which means that all of the rest of the elements in the evens list now *become* the odd-numbered elements.

What's the `~` for? It makes the pattern-match *lazy*. Without it, you'll force the tuple. So, for instance, if I wrote:

```
(head . fst . pairs) [1..]
```

It would not work without the `~`. You could achieve the same effect by writing:

```
pairs = foldr (\x yszs -> (x:snd yszs,fst yszs)) ([],[])
```

Or:

```
pairs = foldr (\x -> uncurry (\ys zs -> (x:zs,ys))) ([],[])
```

Comment: wow, cool. can you explain how it works? looks very magically. what does `~` do?

Comment: @zhangchiqing You could try running it by hand on a small example to see what happens. The key thing here is that in the pattern `(ys, zs)` and the return value `(x:zs, ys)` the lists `ys` and `zs` have switched places. Which means that if `ys` gets the current value then `zs` will get the next, then `ys` again, etc., etc.

Comment: Thinking a bit. I actually like your solution better now. Because this solution can be extended to break a list into 3-tuples, or more. like this
`take 10 $ fst3 $ foldr (\x xs -> (x:trd3 xs, fst3 xs, snd3 xs)) ([], [], []) [1..]`

whereas, the `partition` solution is easier to understand, it can only work for breaking into a pair of two lists

Answer (score 5):

Here is another way. Unlike the others answers at the time of posting, it naturally generalizes to other moduli than 2.

```
Data.List Data.List.Split> transpose . chunksOf 2 $ "ABCDE"
["ACE","BD"]
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel! Your solution is very elegant, just that it requires additional module other than Data.List

Comment: @zhangchiqing Yep. Of course `chunksOf` can be implemented with just `Data.List` functions, but I think code reuse is nice, so I recommend getting familiar with the libraries available.

Comment: "it naturally generalizes to other moduli than 2" because you don't produce a tuple: `[[x | (x,i)<-zip xs [0..], i \`mod\` n == j] | j<-[0..n-1]]`.

Comment: @jferard Yup, not producing a tuple is a key trick for using this technique. But the technique brings other benefits over your proposal; e.g. it makes O(1) passes over the input list, not O(n) (where n is the modulus) like yours, and is friendlier to the GC than yours.

Comment: @DanielWagner you are right: I'm not trying to save my solution, which is probably the worst proposed here (though not so bad), but I had some difficulties to ouput a tuple instead of a list...

Comment: `chunksOf` can readily be implimented in Prelude.

`grpby n ls = [take n (drop x ls)|x<-[0,n..length ls -1]]`

Comment: Or as `map` `grpby n ls=map ((take n).flip drop ls) [0,n..length ls -1]`

Comment: @fpmora Any implementation that calls `length` will not work well on infinite lists (and will be unfriendly to the GC).

Comment: Agree. I.really.despise.length anyway. It's always ugly, too. Recursive might well be better. The `length ls -1 can be removed, but ....

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Since @DanielWagner opened the door, if it's possible to return a list instead of a tuple, an obvious solution is:

```
[[x | (x,i)<-zip xs [0..], i `mod` 2 == j] | j<-[0..1]]
```

It may be generalized to:

```
[[x | (x,i)<-zip xs [0..], i `mod` k == j] | j<-[0..k-1]]
```

For k lists of elements [[e_0, e_k, e_2k, ...], [e_1, e_k+1, e_2k+1, ...], ..., [e_k-1, e_2k-1, e_3k-1,...]].

*For tuples, I leave for the record the previous code, though it's clearly worse than the other answers.*

It's easy to pick even elements with a list comprehension:

```
Prelude> evens xs = [x | (x,i) <- zip xs [0..], even i]
Prelude> evens ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
["A","C","E"]
```

You can do the same with odd elements. But you can also define a function that takes a filter (`even` or `odd`) and returns a function that will select elements:

```
Prelude> toFilter xs = \f -> [x | (x,i) <- zip xs [0..], f i]
Prelude> :t toFilter ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
toFilter ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
  :: (Num t, Enum t) => (t -> Bool) -> [[Char]]
```

`toFilter xs` takes a filter and returns a list:

```
Prelude> l = toFilter ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
Prelude> l even
["A","C","E"]
Prelude> l odd
["B","D"]
```

It's also possible two define a function that takes a function like `toFilter` (`(t -> Bool) -> [[Char]]`) and create a tuple for `even` and `odd` filter:

```
Prelude> :t \tf -> (tf even, tf odd)
\tf -> (tf even, tf odd) :: Integral a => ((a -> Bool) -> t) -> (t, t)
```

Now, it becomes easy to put things together:

```
Prelude> breakByIndexes xs = (\tf -> (tf even, tf odd)) (\f -> [x | (x,i)<-zip xs [0..], f i])
Prelude> breakByIndexes ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
(["A","C"],["B","D"])
Prelude> breakByIndexes ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
(["A","C","E"],["B","D"])
```

Less elegant than @elemx80s, but does the job...

Answer (score 0):

Just remember that ASCII characters have a built in index offset by 65.

import Data.Char (ord)

`ord 'A' - 65` = 0`

Without the offset, the numeric values are even and odd anyway. 'A' is 65, odd.

```
p l = [ [x|x<-l,odd (ord(head x))], [x|x<-l,even (ord(head x))] ]
```

I do love pairs. Once a data set is in pairs it becomes much easier to work with. I came across a function that creates the perfect pairs for this set, it leaves unpaired elements at the end but in the list. It does not create tuples but list pairs are okay, too. The function is chunksOf.

Here it is used as

```
i3 = chunksOf 2 $ words "A B C D E F G H I"
```

To produce the pairs we want. `[["A","B"],["C","D"],["E","F"],["G","H"],["I"]]`

Pairs are even-odd pairs. The odd one at the end is really lacking an odd member. All odd elements of the list are missing the odd member. The odd member extractor has to compensate with filter of pairs with less than two members.

```
[ map (head) l3,   map (last) (filter ((>1).length) l3) ]
```

Produces `[["A","C","E","G","I"],["B","D","F","H"]]`
Pairs carry information, such as even or odd.

And to my shock and awe @DanielWagner points out that `transpose` produces the desired results with the pair list. His is `transpose i3` for an incredibly even more concise solution. Wow!

**Edit 4/15/2018**

I do hope this is final or near final.

```
let ls = words "A B C D E F G"
[[a|(a,b)<-zip ls [0..],bl b]|bl<-[even,odd]]
```

[["A","C","E","G"],["B","D","F"]]